# Open Chrome WebApp from another website/application - Android

Tags: android, android-intent, web-applications, applinks

I am currently trying to link multiple Applications together using Intents and Package names. Only problem is one of the items is a Web App (Chrome save to desktop style). Which obviously doesnt have a package name. Is there a way to give the web app an identifier that another app can target, maybe in the manifest.json file?

I am also looking at running these all on Windows as well so if there is a universal solution then sweet, but main focus is for Android.
Thanks,

Mitchell.